# Existential typing ambiguity

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Apologies for the somewhat contrived example. I've tried to simplify this to the extent that I can without losing the justification:

Suppose I have a multi-parameter typeclass `Relation`:

`class Relation r a b where ....`

And a function which is existentially quantified over such a type:

`neighbours :: forall r a b. Relation r a b => a -> r -> Graph -> [b]`

Now I introduce a couple of instances of `Relation`:

```
data Person = Person String
data Pet = Pet String
data Owns = Owns
data Desires = Desires
instance Relation Owns Person Pet
instance Relation Desires Person Pet
```

Now I would like to write a method which fetches all the pets associated with a given person through some means, without exposing the complexity of implementation:

```
data PetAttachment = AttachOwns | AttachDesires

personPets :: Person -> PetAttachment -> Graph -> [Pet]
personPets person att g = 
    neighbours person r g
  where
    r = case PetAttachment of
      AttachOwns -> Owns
      AttachDesires -> Desires
```

My question is: how do I appropriately type `r`. With no hints, it will try to type as `Owns` and hence fail. I can alternatively hint that it should be existentially typed:

```
r :: forall r. Relation r Person Pet => r
```

But the compiler does not seem able to deduce that `Relation r0 Person Pet`, saying that `r0` is ambiguous:

> relation.hs:26:5:
>       No instance for (Relation r0 Person Pet)
>         arising from a use of ‘neighbours’
>
> The type variable ‘r0’ is ambiguous

Can I persuade `r` to type in such a way as to let this compile?

Full compilable example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

data Graph = Graph

class Relation r a b where
  relation :: (r,a,b) -> Int

neighbours :: forall r a b. Relation r a b => a -> r -> Graph -> [b]
neighbours = undefined

data Person = Person String
data Pet = Pet String
data Owns = Owns
data Desires = Desires
instance Relation Owns Person Pet where
  relation _ = 1
instance Relation Desires Person Pet where
  relation _ = 2

data PetAttachment = AttachOwns | AttachDesires

personPets :: Person -> PetAttachment -> Graph -> [Pet]
personPets person att =
    neighbours person r
  where
    r :: forall r. Relation r Person Pet => r
    r = case att of
      AttachOwns -> Owns
      AttachDesires -> Desires

main :: IO ()
main = undefined
```

Comment: N.b. I would also welcome a better title for this question, or a simpler example!

Comment: What would stop you from doing `personPets person AttachOwns = neighbors person Owns`; `personPets person AttachDesires = neighbors person Desires`?

Comment: Or `personPets person att = case att of { AttachOwns -> neighbors person Owns; AttachDesires -> neighbors person Desires }` if you want to keep an explicit case statement instead of pattern matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two approaches to writing this, one using a GADT and one using a Rank 2 Type.

#### GADT

A [GADT](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Generalised_algebraic_datatype) can capture the constraint on `r` that there must exist an instance for `Relation r Person Pet`. To use a GADT you'll need to add

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
```

`RelationOf a b` will capture the `Relation r a b` instance in the constructor `RelationOf`  due to the `Relation r a b =>` constraint on the constructor.

```
data RelationOf a b where
    RelationOf :: Relation r a b => r -> RelationOf a b
```

`personPets` can then be written much as you desire as

```
personPets :: Person -> PetAttachment -> Graph -> [Pet]
personPets person att =
  case r of (RelationOf r') -> neighbours person r'
  where
    r :: RelationOf Person Pet
    r = case att of
      AttachOwns -> RelationOf Owns
      AttachDesires -> RelationOf Desires
```

The `case` on what was the `neighbors person r` line is required to get the captured `Relation r Person Pet` instance from the `RelationOf` constructor. The instances captured by existentially qualified GADTs can only be recovered by pattern matching against them.

#### Rank 2 Type

To use a [Rank 2 Type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types), you will need to add one of the following

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
```

With a Rank 2 Type, we can split `personPets` into two parts. The first will figure out what `r` is, either `Owns` or `Desires`, and pass that to a universally quantified function in [continuation passing style](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style).

```
withAttachment :: PetAttachment -> (forall r. Relation r Person Pet => r -> c) -> c
withAttachment AttachOwns    f = f Owns
withAttachment AttachDesires f = f Desires
```

`personPets` will call `withAttachment`, passing it a partially applied `neighbours` as the continuation.

```
personPets :: Person -> PetAttachment -> Graph -> [Pet]
personPets person att = withAttachment att (neighbours person)
```

Comment: Note that what is being done here is to solve the problem by *introducing* existential quantification with GADT syntax - the original program in the question does not actually contain any.  The `neighbours :: forall r a b. ...` syntax gives *universal*  quantification (and is actually redundant since Haskell does this by default in this case).  It just so happens that the `ExistentialQuantification` extension accidentally enables `forall` syntax in general, both for existential and universal uses.

Comment: Also, you can use [pattern guards](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard) (standard since H2010) as an alternative to a `case`: `personPets person att | RelationOf r' <- r = neighbours person r'`

Comment: if the `r` argument is supposed to be just a type-level tag, you could use `proxy r` instead as the argument type, and then you don't have to have constructors of the `Owns` and `Desires` types. Moreover, if you want to make this closed-world, you can use `DataKinds`.

Answer (score 2):

A low-tech solution:

```
personPets :: Person -> PetAttachment -> Graph -> [Pet]
personPets person att = case att of
    AttachOwns -> neighbours person Owns
    AttachDesires -> neighbours person Desires
```